# How to activate IIS management tools under Windows 7 embedded standard?

Tags: windows-7, windows, webserver, iis

I try start up IIS management tools, but I only see a white screen in Windows Features.

I have Panel PC with Windows 7 embedded standard. In manual to Panel PC, it's this possible on Windows 7 embedded standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal [Turn Features on or off dialog](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Turn-Windows-features-on-or-off) only works for normal Windows Versions, but not for embedded editions.

To install new Features in Windows 7 embedded standard, you have to download the Toolkit DVD. This includes all features in packages (CAB files).

You have to use [DISM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825236.aspx) from a cmd.exe, which was [started as admin](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token), to install them:

```
DISM /online /add-package /packagepath:"D:\DS\Packages\FeaturePack\x86~winemb-iis~~~~6.1.7601.17514~1.0" /Norestart

DISM /online /add-package /packagepath:"D:\DS\Packages\FeaturePack\x86~winemb-iis-was~~~~6.1.7601.17514~1.0" /Norestart
```

(D: is the mounted ISO of the toolkit). Edit the commands to the features you like to add.

Comment: I'm downloading it and I'll try it! Thank you!